# static getApplicationContext for SQLiteOpenHelper 

Tags: android, sqlite, activerecord, static, sqliteopenhelper

recently I've been trying to create pseudo-AciveRecord-style db calls in my android app and came up with a bunch of class methods like User.all(Context dbContext), User.find(long id, Context dbContext), User.delete(long id, Context dbContext), etc.
By pseudo-AciveRecord I mean I don't plan to make it "real ActiveRecord library" or anything like that. I just want to have an easy to understand db calls in my code and ActiveRecord style is the best for me personally.
So far so good and I don't have any issues having this code for example:

```
    public static Cursor allAsCursor(Context dbContext) {
    DBHelper dBHelper = new DBHelper(dbContext);
    SQLiteDatabase database = dBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor dbQueryResult = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_USERS, null, null, null, null, null, "_id DESC");
    dbQueryResult.getCount();

    database.close();
    dBHelper.close();
    dbContext = null;


    return dbQueryResult;
}
```

But the thing that bothers me is that I pass activity context or something like this all the time when I make a call and I was wondering if it would be a good idea to just give my User class(which has User.find, User.all, etc.) a static variable where it would store application context for every db query? It could be done on app lunch or before the very first query request.

My thinking comes from iOS CoreData thing where you got pretty much static context manager for queries which you get all the time from shared application.

Any thoughts, suggestions, ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: if you mean a user dao class then it seems to me that you are already passing the app context to your db helper class and you use a db reference in its turn provided by db helper for your user dao class. In other words context passed to db helper which returns db used by user dao. That is my understanding.

Comment: yes, and it works well, I have 0 problems with excepted that it is kinda tedious pass the context all the time. This is why I ask if it is a good idea or practice to just keep one static context reference for every query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all down to your design preference I guess, since the method is static i'm guessing all of these DB class methods are static so the class is always used in a static way? Also, are you passing in the Activity context or the application context. If you are using the application context then I would add another static method for setting the context and have a private static reference to the context.

e.g:

```
private static Context context;

public static void setContext(Context context){
    YourDBHelperClass.context = context;
}
```

Now your method can just reference this context instead of having to be passed one every time you make a transaction.

If you are passing in an activity context then I would leave it as is otherwise you risk trying to use a stale context.

Comment: the class is used for querying the db with class/static methods and for creating new User objects with their own instance methods.

Comment: I also been thinking about a Service for more persistent Context reference. Any thoughts on that? Thanks.